# Intermittent video codec error on Chrome for Android (Galaxy Tablet)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, android-mediacodec, chrome-for-android

I am developing a web application for android devices.

I get an intermittent codec error on Chrome for Android when playing a video in my React application. I am using a regular `<video />` tag.

The error never happens on the first time the video loads, upon hitting the back button and then navigating back to the video (Client side routing -- no refresh) the error occurs and the video is not playable. Here are the main logs from `adb logcat`

`mediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xffffec77, actionCode 0, while in state 3`

`MEDIA_ERROR_LOG_ENTRY {"error":"video decoder reinitialization failed"} chromium failed`

`android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffec77`

So I get the codec error.

The weird part is if I keep clicking the play button it will eventually work.

Other noteworthy details are that it works just fine on firefox and my computer (firefox and chome) has no problems. It is only occurring on chrome for android.

any thoughts?

Comment: What is the version of chrome?

Comment: It should be the latest available version for chrome on android as i updated it recently

Comment: what type of video are you playing? Can you reproduce with any video ? I saw some issues on the net related to the same error when videos did have some audio problems

Comment: No this seems to be happening with any video.. But keep in mind that it works if I keep clicking on it

Comment: Ok. When you hit back/forward, do you stop the video before switching ?

Comment: No I dont. when you hit back, React-router conditionally renders another component, and when you go forward it renders the video again. So it's always at initial state.